# How to post to twitter with PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

Hi can anyone help me, I want to be able to post tweets from a PHP script using the twitter API but all the resources i have found and tried so far are old and dont work anymore. anyone have any instructions and/or scripts?

thanks

Comment: a magic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=post+twitter+php

Comment: I wonder if this question ever be closed as exact duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [OAuth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) from Abraham Williams. And a nice tutorial is available [here](http://www.snipe.net/2009/07/writing-your-first-twitter-application-with-oauth/)

Answer (score 1):

Twitter disabled their HTTP Basic Authentication API some time ago.  You will need to look into OAUTH for PHP which is a token based authentication protocol.  You can find information on this from the OAUTH and Twitter sites as well as any number of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I develop an application to recover the tweets and I found more useful to use the [twitter search APIs](http://developer.twitter.com/doc/get/search) through AJAX (JSONP for requests out of the domain).
Through the twitter search APIs you can query the twitter database with the same words you use on the twitter web pages and collect the results that can be viewed how do you like.

However, if you prefer the php scripts I suggest you to use the [twitter libraries](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries).